# How to transform a collection of entities to form elements indexed by their IDs?

Tags: symfony

I'm having trouble rendering a collection of entity IDs as form elements using a simple transformer.

In the main form's `buildForm` method I have this for the `things` collection:

```
    $collection = $builder->create( 'things', 'collection' );
    $collection->addModelTransformer( new EntityTransformer );
    $builder->add( $collection );
```

In the `EntityTransformer` I ensure the form receives scalars indexed by the entities' primary keys:

```
public function transform( $entities ){
    $scalars = array();
    foreach( $entities as $entity ){
        $scalars[ $entity->getId() ] = (string) $entity;
    }
    return $scalars;
}
```

I am now expecting to see form elements with names corresponding to the entity IDs, like `"form[things][998]", "form[things][999]"` etc.. But instead the entity ID keys are ignored and the elements become zero-indexed `"form[things][0]", "form[things][1]"` etc..

It doesn't matter what type of form elements I use, or what I assign as the scalar values of the array, it is the associative mapping which gets lost in all cases.

I know there are other ways to achieve entity mapping, but I want to understand why this approach doesn't work.

My question is simply, why is the collection field ignoring the keys defined by the transformer and reindexing the collection?

Comment: are you sure you want to use a collection instead of a choice widget with multiple => true ?

Comment: yes, because the front end may add new items not in the choice.

Comment: Because collection ignores array keys.  Just the way it was implemented.

Comment: Collection doesn't ignore keys when taking an assoc array directly. Only during transform does this seem to happen

Comment: Its an old question, but does someone know the solution?

Comment: I don't even remember writing it. 3.5 years. Sorry.